# Select Min Datediff from joined tables

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group, date-arithmetic

I'm currently working in BigQuery. I have two tables:

```
Table A {
  id int 
  b_id int
  date timestamp
  }
  
Table B {
  id int 
  long float
  lat float
  date timestamp
}
```

For one `b_id` in `A` there are multiple entries in `B`. I want to **efficiently** join both tables and only use the entry in `B` where `A.b_id = B.id` and the difference between the timestamps is minimal.

My current solution is:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, ABS(DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(A.date), DATETIME(B.date), SECOND)) as timeDiff
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.b_id = B.id    
WHERE ABS(DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(A.date), DATETIME(B.date), SECOND)) = 
(
SELECT MIN(ABS(DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(B2.date), DATETIME(A2.date), SECOND)))
FROM B as B2 
INNER JOIN A as A2
ON B2.driverId = A2.driverId
GROUP BY A2.driverId, B2.rideId
)
```

Problem is that it takes way to much time for a single entry.
Any suggestions on how to improve the query?

Comment: How about adding a condition to the join where the B date shall be between A date and A date plus some interval, and then only taking joins that produce one row ? (Or only taking the first if many rows join per id?)

Comment: How would you check in SQL if it only produced one row and if it does produce more how would you only select the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*, b.*, 
        row_number() over(
            partition by a.b_id
            order by abs(datetime_diff(datetime(a.date), datetime(b.date), second))
        ) rn
    from a
    inner join b on a.b_id = b.id  
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hey @GMB, seems to work great. Could you shortly elaborate how the query works?

Comment: @Bruno: sure. The subquery ranks records having the same `b_id` by their time difference. The record with the smallest date diff gets rank  `1`, which we can then use to filter. You can run the subquery independently and see what it returns.